# ADX Data Pagination for use in client API

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I am exploring using ADX as a timeseries data store for sensor metrics. Our current solution is storing data in MSSQL and I'm testing ADX as an alternative. I was able to set up data ingestion and I can perform basic queries, and with the added aggregation functions, computing insights and statistics seems to be much faster.

As part of the solution, we have a API data access layer used by clients and our web portal to query data for display and analysis use. I am currently transforming the MSSQL queries to the KQL version and I'm hitting a stumble block on data pagination.

We have a function to query historical data using a combination of:

- an start/end date,
- a device identifier,
- and some paging options

  - records per page,
  - current page,
  - column sorting / additional filtering

Currently this is handled in a SQL SP on the back-end, by getting the total number of records and pages (which is set as output on the API so that the front-end can use this data in the table view), then getting the records based on the input parameters and pagination details to return a record set - quite straight forward.

Any suggestions on how to achieve effective pagination using ADX/KQL?

I found a section in the docs on [pagination on stored query results](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/stored-query-results#pagination), but as the queries are dynamic based on user input, so this does not sound like a viable option.

Comment: It is not clear why the fact that you can run any query over the stored query results does not work, can you clarify? In general, once you created the stored query results (which is essentially a temp table) you can run any query over it which allows you to return the pages using a similar protocol to what you have with SQL.

Answer (score 0):

When you paginate (for example viewing result 21-30) you need to consider if you are taking a snapshot of the result and paging through it or viewing live data. If you expect new rows coming in to not affect your pagination, than stored query results is that snapshot. Once you generate it you can select specific rows from it based on your page calculation.